# Python selenium select option from angular js ng-select

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, select, drop-down-menu

I've been trying to make a selection from a drop down but cannot seem to figure out how.

Here's what I'm trying to get:

```
<div _ngcontent-wdj-c58="" class="delivery-group">
    <span _ngcontent-wdj-c58="">Guaranteed Delivery Time:</span>
    <div _ngcontent-wdj-c58="" class="select-container">
        <ng-select _ngcontent-wdj-c58="" class="ng-select ng-select-single ng-select-clearable ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-select-bottom ng-touched" formcontrolname="guaranteedDeliveryTime" notfoundtext="No options" placeholder="Choose" role="listbox">
            <div class="ng-select-container">
                <div class="ng-value-container">
                    <div class="ng-placeholder">Choose</div>
                    <!---->
                    <!---->
                    <div class="ng-input"><input role="combobox" type="text" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" autocomplete="a67359450338" readonly="" aria-expanded="false"></div>
                    </div>
                    <!---->
                    <!---->
                    <span class="ng-arrow-wrapper">
                        <span class="ng-arrow"></span></span>
                        </div><!----></ng-select>
                        <div _ngcontent-wdj-c58="" class="select-validation">
                            <eld-shared-validation _ngcontent-wdj-c58="" message="Specify delivery time." _nghost-wdj-c55="">
                                <!---->
                                </eld-shared-validation>
                                </div></div></div>
```

update : 
when I use selenium Select :

```
a =Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/eld-root/div[2]/div[2]/div/eld-sell-page/div/section/eld-place-offer/div/div/eld-shared-offer-edit-form/form/div[1]/div[1]/div/ng-select'))
```

I got error :

```
UnexpectedTagNameException: Message: Select only works on <select> elements, not on <ng-select>
```

item code html is :

```
<div class="ng-dropdown-panel-items scroll-host">
<div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <!---->
        <!---->
        <div class="ng-option ng-star-inserted ng-option-marked" role="option" aria-selected="false" id="a67359450338-0">
            <!---->
            <!---->
            <span class="ng-option-label ng-star-inserted">20 min</span>
            </div>
            <div class="ng-option ng-star-inserted" role="option" aria-selected="false" id="a67359450338-1">
                <!---->
                <!---->
                <span class="ng-option-label ng-star-inserted">1 h</span
                ></div>
                <div class="ng-option ng-star-inserted" role="option" aria-selected="false" id="a67359450338-2">
                    <!---->
                    <!----><span class="ng-option-label ng-star-inserted">5 h</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ng-option ng-star-inserted" role="option" aria-selected="false" id="a67359450338-3">
                        <!---->
                        <!---->
                        <span class="ng-option-label ng-star-inserted">1 day</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ng-option ng-star-inserted" role="option" aria-selected="false" id="a67359450338-4">
                            <!---->
                            <!---->
                            <span class="ng-option-label ng-star-inserted">2 days</span
                            ></div>
                            <div class="ng-option ng-star-inserted" role="option" aria-selected="false" id="a67359450338-5">
                                <!---->
                                <!---->
                                <span class="ng-option-label ng-star-inserted">7 days</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="ng-option ng-star-inserted" role="option" aria-selected="false" id="a67359450338-6">
                                    <!---->
                                    <!----><span class="ng-option-label ng-star-inserted">28 days</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <!---->
                                    <!---->
                                    <!---->
                                    <!---->
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
```

I try use webdriver ==> Select 
or find element and click() and send_Keys(something) but they doesn't work

the site is https://www.eldorado.gg/ and for see select box should be go to sell and for my case clash of clans and then you see that when want to Fill in the blanks 
but should be sign up 
if is possible check a site and see if 
tnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the exception Select should be used with `<select>` tag.

In your case there is no select html element, so you have to use other option as shown below

```
deliveryTimeEle = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//ng-select[@formcontrolname ='guaranteedDeliveryTime']//input[@role='combobox']")
# click on the combo list box
deliveryTimeEle.click()

# click on the list option ( you can change the option based on the requirement.
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@role='option'][normalize-space(.)='1 day']").click()
```

Comment: I try that but doesn't work
I update my question with more html code

Comment: tank so much
it work
but xpath was :("deliveryTimeEle = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/eld-root/div[2]/div[2]/div/eld-sell-page/div/section/eld-place-offer/div/div/eld-shared-offer-edit-form/form/div[1]/div[1]/div/ng-select/div")
")